# Appropiate way of managing fixed cells in a table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls, reuseidentifier

I have a grouped-style UITableView intended to show a fixed number of sections, each of one having in turn a fixed set of cells, similarly to Settings app. Some of the cells are custom and different between them: some of them have a textfield, another have a switch, another a button. I also have `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cells.

Custom cells are loaded from `nib` files, and I've defined a `strong` property for each cell in the whole table view. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

   if (cell == nil) {

      if (indexPath.section == 0) {

         if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeACell" owner:nil options:nil];
            for (UIView *view in views) {
               if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
               {
                   cell = (TypeACell *)view;
               }
            }

            // set property
            self.typeARow = cell;
         }

        else {
           NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TypeBCell" owner:nil options:nil];
           for (UIView *view in views) {
              if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
              {
                 cell = (TypeBCell *)view;
              }
           }

           // set properties
           if (indexPath.row == 0) {
              self.typeBRow0 = cell;
           }
           else {
              self.typeBRow1 = cell;
           } 
        }
     }

     else {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        // set property
        self.defaultCell = cell;
     }
  }

  return cell;
}
```

For the custom cells, I've also set the reuse identifier to "cell" in their `nib` files. Is this the correct way to proceed when you know beforehand the set of cells for a table that represents for example a form or a menu, like Settings app? Does the reuse identifier be the same for all the cells, or should each different cell have its unique identifier?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use static cells rather than dynamic prototypes. In that case, you can use IBOutlets to each cell from the controller, and you don't implement the data source methods. It would be easiest to do this in a storyboard, rather than xibs, and just design each cell there directly.

Comment: @rdelmar You mean, adding the `UITableViewCell` controls to the same `nib` file where the `UITableView` is, and just create the `IBOutlet`s in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, if you change the table type to static, you can set the number of section and add as many cells as you want to each section. You can then customize each cell how you like. You can either make IBOutlets to the cells themselves (if each is a custom class with IBOutlets to the UI elements), or directly to the UI elements.

Comment: @rdelmar I've my `UITableView` in a `.xib` file, not in a storyboard, how can I set the table as static?

Comment: I don't think you can. Is there a reason you can't do this in a storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar The app was intended to support iOS 4.3 up to latest, and it manages nibs files. Currently, supporting iOS 5+ will be enough, is it possible to use a storyboard for this scenario and keep managing nibs for the rest of the views?

Comment: Sure, you can mix the two.